# display value in GridBoundColumn datagrid as value text

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, telerik

```
<Columns>   
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="shift_start_time" HeaderText="Shift Start Time"
     AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
</Columns>
```

The value in this column is "N" or "M", which comes from database. I want to display "NIGHT" if the value is "N" or "MORNING" if the value is "M" from here. How can I do this?

I want to use the concept of "value" "text" which we do with combo box. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, use the `ItemDataBound` event to change the text:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    if(item != null)
    {
        item["shift_start_time"].Text = item["shift_start_time"].Text.ToString() == "M" ? "Morning" : "Night";
    }
}
```

Note: this needs refactoring, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity way to solve it.
In your entity, define a function:

```
public void MorningORNight(){

if(this.shift_start_time is "M"){DisplayField = "Morning"}
else{DisplayField = "Night"}
}
```

then, you will have a readonly field in your entity as well.

```
    [ReadOnly]
public string DisplayField{ get;set; }
```

Then, at the very beginning, when you fetch the shift_start_time,

```
        public string shift_start_time{
    get{ return _shiftstarttime;}
    set{_shiftstarttime = value;
 this.MorningORNight();}
    }
```

Then, your gridview data field should be DisplayField.
Thanks